# Application Defined error on Simple range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to debug this code for quite some time already does anyone know what is the problem in it?

Code:

```
Sub Find_Field_List()
Dim Last_Field As Integer
Dim Field_List() As Variant
Last_Field = Summary_File.Sheets("Settings").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
Field_List() = Summary_File.Sheets("Settings").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Last_Field, 1))
End Sub
```

Error(highlights line starting with `Field_List()`):

```
RunTime Error 1004
Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error
```

Immediate Window:

```
?Summary_file.Sheets(2).Name
Settings
Split MBSA.xlsm
?Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(5,1)).Count
4 
?Last_Field
5
?Summary_File.Sheets(2).Range(Cells(1,1))
Fields
```

Comment: You need to put `Summary_File.Sheets("Settings")` before each call to `Cells`. If you just put `Cells`, Excel interprets that as cells in the *active sheet,* even if it's in the arguments to a `Range` function that's correctly-scoped.

Comment: There are no parenthesis when assigning range to array change it to `Field_List=Summary_File.Sheets("Settings").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Last_Field, 1))`

Comment: Thanks for the input guys this looks like progress, but a new error comes up after including both of yours solutions RunTime Error 13: Tyep Mismatch

Comment: You are getting type mismatch because you didn't add `.Value`. See the answer that I posted. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: One more tip: Try and avoid the use of `.End(xlDown).Row` You may end up selecting the entire column! If you want to select only till the last row then you may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is very simple in my opinion. The error with your code is that the cells `Cells(2, 1)` and `Cells(Last_Field, 1)` are not fully qualified. And you are getting this error because `Summary_File.Sheets("Settings")` is not active when the code is running. And hence one should always fully qualify the objects.

Try this. Notice the **DOT** before them in the code below.

```
Sub Find_Field_List()
    Dim Last_Field As Integer
    Dim Field_List() As Variant

    With Summary_File.Sheets("Settings")
        Last_Field = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        Field_List = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Last_Field, 1)).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

One more tip: Try and avoid the use of `.End(xlDown).Row` You may end up selecting the entire column! If you want to select only till the last row then you may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: I wish it was that simple, In comments rdhs posted similar solution, but I copy and Pasted yours, and it made progress I guess because I am getting "RunTime Error 13: Type Mismatch".
So its not THAT simple but defienetly thanks.

Comment: Excuse me that was a Mistake.
Thank you very much :)